# How to insert value to external iframe input

Tags: jquery, dom, iframe, javascript-security

I have button and external iframe, and I need click to button to insert to this iframe input some value

```js
$("#button").click(function(){
    $('iframe').find('input').val('value');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='button'>test</button>
<br>
<iframe src="http://www.abc.sk/pridat.aspx" width='900' height='500'></iframe>
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ivoss/hoyq8p76/2/)

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe?rq=1 ? An iframe contains some secruity limits, so you can't handle it like a normal page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main frame and pridat.aspx have to be hosted on the same domain www.abc.sk